# Readonly and updateable field on the view (RAZOR), filled from the model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, asp.net-mvc-2

I need readonly and updateable field on the view (RAZOR), filled from the model.
For example:

```
public class Doc
{
    [UIHint("Readonly")]
    public int? TotalGoodsNumber { get; set; }
    #....
}
```

template Readonly.cshtml:

```
<span>@Model</span>
```

It works fine. Untill I want to update this field by means of jquery on clientside.
Span doesn't have id!

Is it possible to generate id in the template by model field name?

Of course I can wrap this span with div with id, that I make by hand. Not automatically.
But I have a lot of readonly fields… It is not good solution…

Or I can add hidden property to template:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m)
```

Now I have such generated html:

```
    <div class="editor-label">
        <label for="TotalGoodsNumber">Всего наименований товаров</label>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">            
    <span>8</span>

    <input data-val="true" data-val-number="Значение должно быть числовым." data-val-required="Обязательное поле." id="TotalGoodsNumber" name="TotalGoodsNumber" type="hidden" value="8" />
            <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="TotalGoodsNumber" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
    </div>
```

And may try to select necessary span to update text by means of id of hidden field. Because this span located before field with id=” TotalGoodsNumber”.
And I think it is possible to write jquery that can update span text…

But this solution looks a bit complicated…

Thanks for any advices!

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do what you're asking:

1) Ensure your hidden field has a predictable ID (this will default to the property name, but I like setting it explicitly)

```
 @Html.HiddenFor(m => m, new { @id = "TotalGoodsNumber" });
```

2) Give your `span` an `id` as well for ease of selection:

```
 <span id="TotalGoodsNumberDisplay">@Model</span>
```

3) Change the values with jQuery:

```
 $('#TotalGoodsNumber').val('foobar');
 $('#TotalGoodsNumberDisplay').html('foobar');
```